# How do i add files to the startup folder?

Tags: java, c#, xcode, visual-studio

I am trying to make `button1_Click` cause `calc.exe` to be added to the startup folder. I would also like the calculator to randomly pop up on the screen.

I am using Visual Studio 2015.
if also using java what code can I use to add the file to the startup folder on a button click. I tried creating the file with the link of the startup folder but I keep on getting error . file not found even though the file is already present in the projects folder

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;

using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;

using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Hey : Form
    {
        public Hey()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("calc.exe");
            RegistryKey Key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", true);
            Key.SetValue("calc.exe", System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code that you can use:

```
File.Copy(PathToFile, Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Startup));
```

or use File.Move if you don't want to copy your app:

```
File.Move(PathToFile, Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Startup));
```

---

If you want to make your app launch randomly use this code:

```
Thread ithr = new Thread(() =>
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    while(true)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(rnd.Next(10000, 60000) //1000 = 1sec. | random start 10s. - 60s.
        Process.Start(PathToFile);
    }
});
ithr.Start();
```

Answer (score 1):

Following code should work for your problem, It will also open calculator.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var pathToCalculator = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System), "calc.exe");

        var copyOfCalcInStartup= Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Startup), "calc.exe");

        File.Copy(pathToCalculator, copyOfCalcInStartup);

        Process.Start(pathToCalculator);
    }
```